# How do I show there exist infinitely many odd $k$ for which $2^n+k$ is composite with $n\geq 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have tried some examples with odd integer $k$ to check if $2^n+k$ is composite with $n>0$. I find it satisfied with many examples.

My question:

> How do I show there exist infinitely many odd $k$ for which  $2^n+k$ is composite with $n\geq 1$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you looking for $k$ such that $2^n + k$ is composite for all n? Or just for some value of n?

Comment: @Nate  I meant for all n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These $k$ are related to (and possibly equal to) the [Sierpiński numbers](https://oeis.org/A076336), which are those positive odd $k$ such that $k 2^n + 1$ is composite for all $n$.

A positive odd number $k$ is in your set if there are primes $p_1, \ldots, p_m < k $ such that for every $n$, $2^n + k$ is divisible by at least one of these.
For example, take the primes $3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 37, 73$.  Note that the orders of $2$ mod each of these primes are $2, 4, 3, 12, 18, 36, 9$, so mod each of these primes, $2^n +k$ is periodic in $n$ with period dividing $36$.  If, for example, $k \equiv 2 \mod 3$, $\equiv 2 \mod 5$, $\equiv 3 \mod 7$, $\equiv 11 \mod 13$, $\equiv 11 \mod 19$, $\equiv 6 \mod 37$, and $\equiv 9\mod 73$,
then you can check that $2^n + k$ is divisible by at least one of the primes
for all $n$ from $0$ to $35$, and therefore for all $n$.  By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there are infinitely many such $k$ (the least of which is  $78557$).

Comment: Nice proof , i think you are used the part of theorem which it's related to Erdos. theorem ( k.2^n+1) is composit for all n with ood integer k or Fermat numbers : F0,F1 ,F2,F3,F4 with p> F4 ....